# SVD of Matrix Multiplication in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix-multiplication, svd

I am currently trying to find the singular values of a large amount of matrix multiplications (about 1000 matrices) of 4 by 4 matrices in matlab. I am running into issues of overflow quite a bit but is not the main source of my question. I have done the matrix multiplication in two different ways. My first method is to calculate the matrix multiplication directly. i.e. `Mn*….*M1=M`. This method gives me a matrix with elements on the order 1.0e+80. And then from here finding the singular values from `[D]=svd(M)`. 
My second method is using QR factorization. I first do `[Q1,R1]=qr(M1)`. Then for the next step, I calculate `[Q2,R2]=M2*Q1`. This makes it so that `M=Qn* Rn*…*R2*R1`. I know that `Rn*…*R2*R1` should have the same singular values as M so hopefully `[D]=svd(Rn*…*R2*R1)` should give me the same answer as in my first method. However the singular values are on the order of 1.0e+61 larger in the first method as compared to the second method. What source could be causing this massive discrepancy, which method is more reliable, and is there a better way of approaching this problem? Many thanks in advance

Comment: Please tell me you are not using variable name for enumerating your matrices, especially if you have 1000 matrices.

Comment: Also, by  "overflow" you mean memory overflow? SVD should give you a reasonable result even for singular matrices. Maybe the singular values are indeed expected to be either zero or very large? I'd guess it would be difficult to even come up with examples that would result in nearly singular matrices (maybe if evey M is a rotation matrix of sorts, but otherwise...)

Comment: Mefitico, I am not using variable names, this was simply to express the "theory" of the methods, sorry for the confusion. And by overflow, I do mean memory overflow. Once again, this doesn't seem to be the main problem, I provided it as some information in case it seemed to be relevant to someone who knows my problem better. The main issue is why  my two methods seem to be giving me such drastically different answers.

Comment: I'm thinking here that QR factorization should be expected to introduce numerical errors. Those errors probably grow quite fast due to each multiplication `[Qn, Rn]=Mn*Q(n-1)`. So it is not a surprise for me that you  get wildly different results. But, anyway, If test in python with random matrices:

 `m=np.random.randn(4, 4)
for i in range(100):
    m = np.dot(m, np.random.randn(4,4))

un, sn, vhn = np.linalg.svd(m, full_matrices=True)

print(sn)`

I get the singular values to be in the order of 1e23 and 1e7, with 100 multiplications.   With 1000 multiplication it goes up to 1e280.